# SSH Tunnel Not Working As Expected

Tags: mac-osx, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to tunnel through a public IP to a private server's port 80.  I know for a fact that apache is running on port 80 because if I ssh into the public IP I can access the private server via lynx just fine.  The command I am using is as follows:

```
ssh <remote_public_id> -N -L 9080:<private_ip_of_other_server>:80
```

Then accessing http://localhost:9080 says unable to connect.  I'm doing this from OSX.  Running ssh -version I get the following in case it matters:

```
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009
```

As requested by Ernest, here is some debug. This is after I enter my password.  Removed IP address for security purposes.

```
debug3: packet_send2: adding 48 (len 63 padlen 17 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:9080 forwarded to remote address <private_ip>:80
debug3: channel_setup_fwd_listener: type 2 wildcard 0 addr NULL
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 9080.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 4 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 9080.
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
```

And then this debug when I make a request:

```
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 9080 for zmanda port 80, connect from ::1 port 64917, nchannels 5
debug3: channel 3: status: The following connections are open:
  #2 direct-tcpip: listening port 9080 for zmanda port 80, connect from ::1 port 64912 (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 6/6 cfd -1)
  #3 direct-tcpip: listening port 9080 for zmanda port 80, connect from ::1 port 64917 (t4 r1 i3/0 o3/0 fd 7/7 cfd -1)
  #4 direct-tcpip: listening port 9080 for zmanda port 80, connect from ::1 port 64918 (t3 r-1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 8/8 cfd -1)

debug3: channel 3: close_fds r 7 w 7 e -1 c -1
debug2: channel 4: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 4: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 4: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 4: obuf empty
debug2: channel 4: close_write
debug2: channel 4: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 4: read<=0 rfd 8 len 0
debug2: channel 4: read failed
debug2: channel 4: close_read
debug2: channel 4: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 4: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 4: send eof
debug2: channel 4: input drain -> closed
debug2: channel 4: send close
debug3: channel 4: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 4: rcvd close
debug3: channel 4: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 4: is dead
debug2: channel 4: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 4: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 9080 for zmanda port 80, connect from ::1 port 64918, nchannels 4
debug3: channel 4: status: The following connections are open:
  #2 direct-tcpip: listening port 9080 for zmanda port 80, connect from ::1 port 64912 (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 6/6 cfd -1)
  #4 direct-tcpip: listening port 9080 for zmanda port 80, connect from ::1 port 64918 (t4 r1 i3/0 o3/0 fd 8/8 cfd -1)

debug3: channel 4: close_fds r 8 w 8 e -1 c -1
```

Comment: Well, fancy meeting you here :) I would try running with `ssh -v -v -v` to get some extra debug info, and then report back. That command certainly looks right to me.

Comment: Is connecting to other_server via IP and not hostname causing it to have problems serving the page because it's doing virtual hosts and needs a hostname header to know what to serve?

Comment: Ernest, do I know you? ;)  I've added some debug.

Comment: blahdiblah - I tried with the hostname and I get the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue was a few things.

1. The web application is running over SSL so I had to do port 443 instead of 80
2. For whatever reason, you can't forward 443 to a different local port.  So I had to forward to 443.

The final command looked like this:

```
sudo ssh gdboling@<public_ip> -N -L 443:<private_host>:443
```

Comment: You can't do a port redirect for 443? Is that specific to the OSX port of SSH?

Comment: The guy that I got the answer from was using Winblows.  I don't think that you can't.  It's just that it doesn't work well with this particular web application.  It could be the app, I really don't know for sure.

Comment: This is not specific to the port, but (my guess is) to SSL. I had exactly the same issue with some enterprise software running a web interface on port 8443. When i made a tunnel from 8000, it did not work. When i nicely tunneled 8443 to 8443, everything was just fine. (OSX Mavericks)